# how to scroll a web application in watir

Tags: scroll, watir

How do I scroll a web application in Watir ?

I have tried`@browser.send_keys :space`

This just brings the whole page down. But I have a scroll within the application, I need to scroll the vertical scroll bar down & up in my automation testing, Please help me !

Thanks!

```
<div dojoattachpoint="containerNode" class="containerNode tabContentPane typeNavigationSingleChild" style="overflow: auto; left: 5px; top: 10px; width: 1549px; height: 535px;">
  <div pageid="lifecycle_theme_home_page_dashboard_pageId" id="lifecycle_theme_home_page_dashboard_pageId" style="height: 535px; padding: 0px; width: 1549px;" widgetid="lifecycle_theme_home_page_dashboard_pageId" title="" role="group" class="dijitContentPane wcs-nullLayout">
```

Comment: Can you please share the html of the page, or at least the part that scrolls? Are we talking about scrolling an iframe or something like a div tag?

Comment: Do you want the test if the *browser* scroll bar works?

Comment: The scroll is for the web app displayed on the browser, scroll bar is of application & it has div tag.

Comment: <div dojoattachpoint="containerNode" class="containerNode tabContentPane typeNavigationSingleChild" style="overflow: auto; left: 5px; top: 10px; width: 1549px; height: 535px;"><div pageid="lifecycle_theme_home_page_dashboard_pageId" id="lifecycle_theme_home_page_dashboard_pageId" style="height: 535px; padding: 0px; width: 1549px;" widgetid="lifecycle_theme_home_page_dashboard_pageId" title="" role="group" class="dijitContentPane wcs-nullLayout">

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1) Scroll to Last Element**

I think Vinay's approach should work. However, in the current form, it assumes that the element already exists on the page. I am guessing the element you want is only visible once you scroll far enough. So what you can do is scroll to the last element in the div.

**Watir-Webdriver**

In Watir-Webdriver:

```
div_with_scroll = browser.div(:class => 'containerNode tabContentPane typeNavigationSingleChild')
div_with_scroll.elements.last.wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

**Watir-Classic**

In Watir-Classic, it is different since it does not use selenium-webdriver:

```
div_with_scroll = browser.div(:class => 'containerNode tabContentPane typeNavigationSingleChild')
div_with_scroll.elements.last.document.scrollIntoView
```

**Solution 2) Use ScrollTop Property**

As an alternative, if the above does not work, you can set the `scrollTop` property to move the div element's scrollbar. This worked for an application that I was working on that had content that was only loaded once you scrolled to the bottom.

**Watir-Webdriver**

To jump the scrollbar to the bottom, which in theory should trigger the below content to load, set the `scrollTop` property to the `scrollHeight`:

```
div_with_scroll = browser.div(:class => 'containerNode tabContentPane typeNavigationSingleChild')
scroll_bottom_script = 'arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight'
div_with_scroll.browser.execute_script(scroll_bottom_script, div_with_scroll)
```

To jump back to the top, set the `scrollTop` to zero.

```
div_with_scroll = browser.div(:class => 'containerNode tabContentPane typeNavigationSingleChild')
scroll_top_script = 'arguments[0].scrollTop = 0'
div_with_scroll.browser.execute_script(scroll_top_script, div_with_scroll)
```

You can also use any value in between depending on where you need to go to.

**Watir-Classic**

In Watir-Classic, you can set the `scrollHeight` more directly:

```
div_with_scroll = browser.div(:class => 'containerNode tabContentPane typeNavigationSingleChild')

#Go to bottom
div_with_scroll.document.scrollTop = div_with_scroll.document.scrollHeight

#Go to top
div_with_scroll.document.scrollTop = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

if the element is at the bottom of the page, it will load more content:

```
browser.element.wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Comment: Its not for testing if scroll bar works. Its more for testing loading of page, as we scroll the bar the below content is loaded. Also here is a snap shot of the div tag that actually has scroll bar which I need to scroll.

Comment: <div dojoattachpoint="containerNode" class="containerNode tabContentPane typeNavigationSingleChild" style="overflow: auto; left: 5px; top: 10px; width: 1549px; height: 535px;"><div pageid="lifecycle_theme_home_page_dashboard_pageId" id="lifecycle_theme_home_page_dashboard_pageId" style="height: 535px; padding: 0px; width: 1549px;" widgetid="lifecycle_theme_home_page_dashboard_pageId" title="" role="group" class="dijitContentPane wcs-nullLayout">

Comment: browser.element.wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view did not help :-(

Answer (score 0):

Using Watir-Classic, the second method Justin Ko provided works great for iterating through a scrollable section to find something specific. Here's an example of that:

```
div_with_scroll = browser.div(:class => 'containerNode tabContentPane typeNavigationSingleChild')
scroll_value = 50 # change this number to match how much you want to scroll each iteration
max_loop = div_with_scroll.document.scrollHeight / scroll_value
if div_with_scroll.document.scrollHeight % scroll_value > 0 # accounts for any remainder height
    max_loop = max_loop + 1
end
for i in 0..max_loop do
    div_with_scroll.document.scrollTop = i * scroll_value # moves the scrollbar
    if div_with_scroll.text.include? 'Search Text'
        puts 'Search Text found in iteration: ' + i.to_s()
        break # exits the loop when found
    end
end
```

There may be a more efficient way to do what I'm doing here, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript (eg. bottom of page):

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

use a correct javascript executor to achieve this result - below i have written some code to show you the 'in my opinion' best and most reliable way to achieve this:

BOTTOM OF PAGE:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webapplication).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - 5)");
```

TOP OF PAGE:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webapplication).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight 0)");
```

you can also set different values to scroll to different heights - for example the scroll to bottom code i have set to 5px from the bottom of the page. good luck, hope this is of somewhat use to you.